# What can happen in a month?

Tags: campaign-development, time

So at some point, my players decided that what was supposed to be a mostly nameless starting city for them to use a base of operations until they ventured out had to become their own personal fortress. They spent half the loot of their first quests on building a wall, ordered a literal boatload of weapons from a group of Hobgoblins, and then set about mapping out the surroundings.

However, last session they took a side-quest for someone they met in town (the replacement of the sorceror who died before that) and left for a trip through the giant Kobold Empire.

It's a two week trip to the destination, and it'll be another two week trip back. That means this small city, shortly after having received a huge boost to its economy and defensive potential, has been basically abandoned by the people who were doing so much to build it up. And the people staying behind have no idea when (or if) they're coming back, since it's a dangerous trip.

When the party returns to the city, I want them to both feel that time hasn't been standing still, that their investment in the city is paying off (ie; having it burned to the ground would be lame) and that things are happening that they need to control. But I'm not sure what could reasonably happen to a frontier city with a lot of surplus money in a month of time. So I'm looking for some help.

Some information about the city; there's about 1000 inhabitants, it exists mostly because of logging and ship-building, the nearest human kingdom is a few days sailing up the river, they are (at this time) independent because they were too small and unimportant to be taxed and there's a number of other races in the area, most notably Goblins which have recently (with help of the PCs) vanquished their old enemies, the Orcs, and are now free to expand and the giant Kobold Empire, which basically doesn't care about them. There is also an abandoned Dwarven city near them, which the Goblins are currently taking over (it was the warzone in which they fought the Orcs)

I'd be most interested in things that could be happening *in* the city that're directly related to the effort the players themselves have put into making it better, but something that ties the city in with the surrounding area is also acceptable.

Comment: At the very least this needs a system tag so we could apply any system downtime/passage of time rules appropriately, but even then it might be too broad.

Comment: You're asking a very broad question. Lots of things can happen in a month, and it depends on how much turmoil there is in a particular area. Take a look at real life and how much news can come out of one city in a month. There's no mechanical way to answer this, or even an experience-based answer. I'd recommend rethinking the question

Answer (score 2):

An influx of wealth into a city, combined with fancy new defenses and fortifications? Sounds like time for some **militaristic political intrigue!**

Two things I think would take off in a town that is pumped up like that.

**Thieves**

A new influx of wealth means more people coming to take that wealth. Word can spread in a month about the tiny ship building village that suddenly has coin circulating. Not full on thieves guilds, but consider bandits and pick-pockets coming to take the coin of the newly wealthy merchants inside city walls. The formerly peaceful, sleepy little town now has a crime wave, and the PCs need to work with a newly established constabulary to crack down on it!

**Military practices**

A new defense fortification and a crime spree? Now we need a militia or police force. The town's government needs to start training, and quick. And hey, with this new found defensible town and trained guards, maybe they can start expanding their territory? Maybe the peace they had with all of those surrounding races can start to be a little strained as the town flexes its new found muscles. And anytime a guard or militia is formed, there has to be a leader among them. How much power does THAT guy (gal) want? Do they push against the governor to try to exert more control? The town's power structure can now turn in flux, and the PCs need to decide who is best to rule (or at least govern when they're not there to rule).

Give mechanical and story implications for their choices. If, long term, they side with the Captain of the Guard, then their city may have lower crime and a stronger military presence, but also be a little totalitarian and pick more fights with outsiders.

If the governor is chosen, perhaps the economic growth of the city continues, but they are at risk of getting attacked by their neighbors or succumbing to established thieves guilds.